# Локализация сайта: Отчёт о пропущенных и неиспользуемых сообщениях (Quasar, I18n)

Tags: локализация, i18n, интернационализация, quasar.js, quasar-framework

Необходимо создать отчёт о пропущенных и неиспользуемых переводах. Для Vue-проектов существует такая штука как **vue-cli-plugin-i18n**, которая добавляет команду `vue-cli-service i18n:report`.

У меня же проект на Quasar Framework и я думал, что без труда установлю эту штуку и в него. Как же я ошибался. А ничего подобного для Quasar найти не могу.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нет ли для Quasar подобного расширения или как установить vue-cli-plugin-i18n в квазаровский проект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После достаточно продолжительных поисков нашёл такую прекрасную вещь, как vue-i18n-extract. Данное расширение устанавливается как во вью-проекты, так и в квазаровские, позволяет печатать отчёт как в консоль, так и в JSON-файл.

Comment: Благодарю, меня тоже эта тема интересовала, очень полезно.
Вынесу вопрос в наш FAQ - https://github.com/DmitrijOkeanij/Quasar_Ru/blob/master/FAQ.md

Comment: Это честь для меня! Рад был помочь)